# source code to get read write permission on files and folders and save in the table

Tags: c#

Please find a source code to get read and write permission on files and folders. I was google about it but no one helped me.

Example

Output

```
Path                                       Read                                                        Write
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\\WINDOWS                 Administrators, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM,Power Users, Users Users              Administrators, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

I want to get all the read write permission of all folders, subfolders and files which is selected by the user and save the above three columns data in sql table. 
How can i do this.
source code to get permission is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of looking for *existing working code* to do this, look for *how* to do it. Then try it yourself. *Then* come back here and ask if you still need help.

Comment: Google is an application and not a human.

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully get you started:

Call [Directory.GetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol.aspx) on the directory which gives you a [DirectorySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx) instance that has a [GetAccessRules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.commonobjectsecurity.getaccessrules.aspx) which will give you a list of [AuthorizationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.authorizationrule.aspx) and if you cast that to [FileSystemAccessRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule.aspx) then you should be able to get out the [FileSystemRights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx) and [IdentityReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.authorizationrule.identityreference.aspx) to get out the information you want.